# how to watch a movie from remote server (I have full access to) using VLC player on Win 10 pc?

Tags: ubuntu, vlc-media-player, media

How to watch a movie from remote server (I have full access to) using VLC player on Win 10 pc?

The files are uploaded into `/home/****/movies/` and have permissions set like this: `?rwxrwxr--`.

```
???@ubuntu:~$ ls -lah ~/movies/
total 28K
drwxrwxr-- 7 ??? 4.0K Jul  2 00:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 9 ??? 4.0K Jul  2 00:20 ..
drwxrwxr-- 3 ??? 4.0K Jun 27 22:02 Hell.or.High.Water.2016.1080p.BluRay.x265-RARBG
drwxrwxr-- 3 ??? 4.0K Jun 27 21:43 Joker.2019.1080p.BluRay.x265-RARBG
drwxrwxr-- 3 ??? 4.0K Jul  1 01:42 K-PAX.2001.1080p.WEBRip.x264-RARBG
drwxrwxr-- 3 ??? 4.0K Jul  2 00:30 Manchester.by.the.Sea.2016.1080p.BluRay.x265-RARBG
drwxrwxr-- 3 ??? 4.0K Jul  1 11:48 The.Northman.2022.1080p.BluRay.x265-RARBG
```

What I want is to open VLC player on my local pc (Win 10) and get access to this server, browse to the `~/movies/Hell.or.High.Water.2016.1080p.BluRay.x265-RARBG/` directory, play the video and load up subtitles.

Comment: There are several ways to achieve that. Which is easier depends on what win10 supports and I (luckily) have no idea. If the client was running a sensible OS I would probably go with setting up an NFS server on the server. As the client runs a microsoft thing, CIFS is probably better in this case - my experiences with that are 20 years old, but back then you should install and configure samba on the server to support that.

Comment: @Henrik supports the community Do you suggest it's easier to achieve this goal using Linux client machine??

Comment: I don't know much about the Windows version, but the Linux version of VLC can serve as a UPnP client, so you could try something like [MiniDLNA](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MiniDLNA).